# How to pass userId from browser to protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, protractor

So I have used *ngFor in my angular2 component to render users.

```
<ul>
    <li *ng-for="let user of users">
      <input [(ng-model)]="user.name">          
      <button (click)="remove(user._id)">Remove</button>
      <a [routerLink]="['/edit',user._id]">
          <i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now in my protractor test, when I am clicking this link its not navigating to edit component.

So What I want to do is:

Navigate to editComponent by passing any of the user._id but I dont know how to pass user._id from template to protractor e2e test.

below is my test:

```
it('should redirect to edit', () => {       
    browser.get('/edit/'+user._id); //here I want to pass user._id which is inside *ngFor of browser       
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

any way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `evaluate()` method to extract the value form scope variable.Look at below example.

```
it('should redirect to edit', () => {       
    element(by.buttonText("Remove")).evaluate("user._id").then(function(userId){
       browser.get('/edit/'+userId);      
       browser.waitForAngular(); 
    })
});
```

Comment: @BhushanGadekar i am not familiar with angular2. what do you mean by routerLink?

Comment: @Sudharshan you have used by.buttonText on remove button.. but I want to click the anchor link here. i.e. edit

Comment: can you try this instead `element(by.css("button ~ a"))`